# Quick Set Builder Notation Question (Universal Quantifier)

Tags: logic, notation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

I have a question about notation of the set $S=\{(x, mx+y_o)|\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ in the link above.

Why do they put the universal quantifier here? Shouldn't the set $S$ instead be $S=\{(x, mx+y_o)|x\in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: I believe either way is fine.

Comment: They really should not include the quantifier; it belongs as part of an assertion, and there is no assertion here. The officially correct version is the second one you give. Of course the meaning is clear, so it might be a little extreme to call the version with the quantifier _wrong_...

Comment: @Naji No, there should be no quantifier there, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At best, it seems a bit redundant. The way you would read that statement is,

"the set of solutions is all the ordered pairs such that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y=mx+y_0$"

So there is already a universal quantifier in the statement (for all ordered pairs such that). At worst I'd say it's grammatically incorrect (not a well-formed formula).

Comment: It is not "a bit redundant". It would be incorrect to use the quantifier.

Comment: Sure. It is syntactically incorrect, but it is not incorrect in that it conveys a different meaning. It conveys the same meaning and it makes sense to say, "for all ordered pairs (x,mx+y_0) such that there is a pair for every real x". There is just no need to say "for every" because that is conveyed by saying all ordered pairs with the condition that x be real.

Comment: No. It does not convey any meaning.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Are you denying it has meaning because there is no standard interpretation of such a string of symbols?

Comment: Of course. It is not a matter of your own private way of "reading" stuff.